# Entity propetytype as object in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm looking information, how use entity propety type as object.

I have entity Products and Categories. In Products Entity propety category is type object. How pass object Categories to that propety? Any ideas how that use? Any Example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: don't use the object type. Instead use [Doctrine's association mappping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html).

I would advice to use the [one-to-many bidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) or the [many-to-many bidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) if you want to be able to have one product in multiple categories too.

Follow these steps:

- Place the examples in your own entity and change the annotations from @... to @ORM\...
- generate the getters and setters with the commandline:
  `app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle`
- update your database schema:
  `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Now check your created getter and setter functions. You might find something like getProducts() removeProduct() and addProduct().